# How to use JSON in ANDROID?

Tags: php, android, json

This is my php request:

```
<?php

// parametri del database
$db_host = "localhost";
$db_user = "unisadb";
$db_password = "";
$db_name = "my_unisadb";
$db = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user1, $db_password);
if ($db == FALSE)
    die ("Errore nella connessione. Verificare i parametri..."); 
mysql_select_db($db_name, $db)
    or die ("Errore nella selezione del database. Verificare i parametri...");
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Utente");
while($e=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
        $output[]=$e;

print(json_encode($output));
mysql_close();

?>
```

and this is JSON response

```
[
{
    "idUtente": "1",
    "Nome": "Roberto",
    "Cognome": "D'Antuono",
    "Valutazione": "0"
},
{
    "idUtente": "2",
    "Nome": "Luca ",
    "Cognome": "Carbone",
    "Valutazione": "90"
}
]
```

Can you help me with a guide or a sequential "how to" to get data by this json?

Comment: show code what you have tried to parse posted json. because json is very easy which u have posted with question to parse

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest and best way is to use Gson or Jackson. You can download Gson from here http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.3.1 and all you need is to create domain objects for your Json structure, something like

```
public class Utente {
private int idUtente;
private String Nome;
private int Cognome;
private double Valutazione;

... geters and setters...

}
```

and deserialize it like this:

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
Utente utente = gson.fromJson(response.toString(), Utente.class);

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to get the all name from the json . so the code will be like this .

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json_string); // download and pass the json string here
    String []name = new String[jsonArray.length()];
    for(int p=0;p<jsonArray.length();p++){
        try {
            JSONObject singleIndexObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(p);
            name[p] = singleIndexObject.getString("Nome"); // Name is the name of the key from your Json String
            // Add other value same as previous .
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

JSONArray never null. You must download and pass the Json formatted String into the parameter. For download you can use [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html)